Transformers Operations Order
What is better ?

A) add attention, then add FFN. So I think that today's version of Transformers force the FFN to correct the Attention impacte and to do the FFN work. Maybe it's intended, but I never read it anywhere.
B) I think that Into the FFN should go an "Attentionned" X input (from the base line), and then to the base line, should be applied the small change that the FFN computed from "Attentionned" base line. This way, there is no "Noise" from Attention, that is applied to Base line.
But Maybe I am just wrong, and the Attention mechanism shouldn't be interpreted as noise, but as usefull information.

Can the man who closed for Duplicate comment under this post. I need to talk to you
